# Drop Down menu disappears when mouse hover

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu, mousehover

I have made a test page for my site

[Demo Link](http://www.ritcom.tk/demo)

The dropdown menu here is disappearing whenever I hover the mouse over it.

I have seen and tried the various solution already mentioned in the forum but none seem to help correct it.
Please help, I want to solve this.

Comment: we are going to see some code in order to help you.

Comment: Error in console :
"404 Not Found - http://www.ritcom.tk/demo/SlickNav/jquery.slicknav.min.js"
jquery.....min.js
"404 Not Found - http://www.ritcom.tk/demo/SlickNav/slicknav.css"

Comment: I had tried that menu and forgot to remove it from the header. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change

```
/*Display the dropdown on hover*/
 nav#nav-main ul li a:hover + .hidden, .hidden:hover {
display: block;
}
```

to

```
/*Display the dropdown on hover*/
   nav#nav-main ul li:hover ul{
   display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to make following changes in css. Make a hover effect on `li`. Also you need to set the `position` and `z-index` of `header-top` to work the dropdown menu properly

```
.header-top{
  height: 72px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 90;
}

ul.hidden {
  position: absolute;
}

nav#nav-main ul li:hover a + .hidden { 
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: This fix is working as well. Although, I'll go with the above mentioned answer as it requires minimal editing. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This is the structure of your menus:

```
<li>
  <a href="#">About ￬</a>
  <ul class="hidden">
    <li><a href="#">Who We Are</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">What We Do</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

and the submenu ul si displayed with this css rule

```
nav#nav-main ul li a:hover + .hidden, .hidden:hover { display: block; }
```

Meaning that when you hover the link, the submenu is displayed. But when you move the mouse to the submenu you're no longer over the link, so the submenu is hidden again. You have to change the css rule so the menu is displayed when you hover the whole menu li, and you'll be fine:

```
nav#nav-main ul li:hover .hidden { display: block; }
```

Comment: Hi, on applying this change the drop-down stops appearing at all. Sorry this doesn't work.